# Slick generating query with backtick for Oracle

Tags: scala, slick

I am using slick with oracle. Things are fine except, slick generated queries are having backticks in the query which oracle does not support. Any idea/pointer from anyone how to remove those backticks please?

Example Query:

```
select `merchant_code`, `merchant_name`, `merchant_address`, `merchant_mcc`, `account_number`, `ifsc` from `merchant_details` where `merchant_code` = '1024';
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it... Seems I was using MysqlProfile instead of OracleProfile.